# C Programming ScanF multiple input one file

Tags: c, input, variable-assignment, scanf

Trying to figure out how to read in multiple variables through a file. for example i know how to read in one, if i have a file called "datainput" which has the line of text "150" and then in my program if I have int value; and then scanf("%d", &value); when i run the program with the file it reads the file and then applies it to my variable. but what I am trying to do now is something similar but instead read in 2 values, so say in my text file i will have "3.1, 3.4" something like this and then put it on variable 1 and 2 something like that. anyone have any ideas?

Comment: It would be much easier to understand this question if you posted your code, rather than just attempting to explain it all in words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To read in two values all you have to do is add an additional format specifier to the `scanf()` call:

```
scanf("%d %d", &value1, &value2); //reads two values
```

Also, just to note if you are reading from a file you need to use the function `fscanf` has a similar format to `scanf` except that you need pass a pointer to the file you are working with:

```
  char inFileName[] = "input.txt";

  FILE *inFile;

  /* open the input file */  
  inFile = fopen(inFileName, "r");

  fscanf(inFile, "%d %d", &value1, &value2); //reads two values from FILE inFile
```

Comment: Would it just use the space as the separator?

Comment: @CalvinMoss if the space is how they are separated in your file, then yes. You could have any other delimiter in your file you want, (i.e if you separated your values with commas: `value1, value2`, then your scanf would be `scanf("%d, %d", &value1, &value2);`

Comment: No, you read from files with `fscanf()`, I was getting to that part

Answer (score 1):

If your format is:

```
3.1, 3.4
```

Try:

```
float float1, float2;
int num_things_read = scanf("%f, %f",&float1,&float2);
```

[The `scanf()` man page](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/scanf/) has a full listing of all the formats you can use. The format string can be used to specify the format of the input much like `printf()` can be used to specify the format of the output (although not exactly the same).

There's also a short series of examples [here](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=564).

As a commenter points out, if you're reading from a file, you'll need to use `fscanf()`:

```
int num_things_read = fscanf(stream, "%f, %f",&float1, &float2);
```

Where `stream` is something you've previously opened with [`fopen()`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/fopen/), such as a file.

Comment: Would it just use the space as the separator? for example if i did 2.2 -4.0 would it work if i just did scanf("%f %f", &value1, &value2); instead of the commas

Comment: A space in the format string corresponds to zero or more white space characters in the input - so if your format string is `"%f, %f"`, but your input is `"1.2,      1.5"`, both values are read.

Comment: So how would one get it to read both values if the input file only had one space between the values rather then a ,

Comment: The OP asks about a use of scanf that he wants to increase to reading two variables. I'll add a note about reading from a file.

Comment: scanf reads nput from the standard input stream not from the file.fscanf() reads input from the stream pointer stream.

Comment: @CalvinMoss just drop the `,` from the format string - do a `scanf("%f %f", ... );`